# How to get which ID is similar after cv2.BFMatcher.knnMatch() implementation?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have 2 cameras that see the similar objects from different perspective. First I detected the objects with their tracking ids, then find the feature descriptors for each detected objects. You can see the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRY4c.png) that contains values for both cam1 and cam2. Normally, id1 on cam1 is the same object id2 on the cam2.

My code is :

```
if feature_data_cam1.shape != () and feature_data_cam2.shape != () : 

            matches = self.bf.knnMatch(feature_data_cam1,feature_data_cam2,k=2)
            
            # Apply ratio test to eliminate undesirable matches
            good = []
            for m,n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
                    good.append([m])
            
            print(matches)
```

As an output, I got cv2.DMatch that gives me the matched keypoints. I would like to know, which ID is similar.(like : ID1 on cam1 is the same object called ID2 on cam2.) How can I get this information from Dmatches?

Comment: do you need help understanding the operation of `knnMatch`? what does the documentation say, and what questions remain?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I understood the knnMatch. As an output I would like to get returned the which arrays are matched. But I always see the implementations that draw the matches between images. How can I get the matched arrays as an output?